# Extract keys from Dictionary where all the values in the value are equal to searched value

Tags: linq, linq-to-entities

```
    var myDictionary = new Dictionary<int, List<DateTimeOffset?>>
    {
        {1234, new List<DateTimeOffset?> {new DateTimeOffset(DateTime.Today), null, new DateTimeOffset(DateTime.Today)}},
        {2134, new List<DateTimeOffset?> {null, new DateTimeOffset(DateTime.Today), new DateTimeOffset(DateTime.Today)}},
        {2345, new List<DateTimeOffset?> {null, null, new DateTimeOffset(DateTime.Today)}},
        {3451, new List<DateTimeOffset?> {new DateTimeOffset(DateTime.Today).AddDays(-1), null, new DateTimeOffset(DateTime.Today)}}
    };
```

When I search by DateTimeOffset(DateTime.Today), I only want to select or extract the keys 1234, 2134 and 2345 and not the last one 3451 because not all values for this key are equal to the searched datetimeoffset value DateTimeOffset(DateTime.Today) ignoring the null values.

I require a linq query for this please. This query seems to do it but how do ou extract the keys of the dictionary ???

```
var mySearchResult = myDictionary.Values.Where(v1 => v1.All(d2 => d2.HasValue == false || d2.Value == new DateTimeOffset(DateTime.Today)));
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me:

```
var keys =
    myDictionary
        .Where(kvp => kvp.Value.All(d =>
            d.HasValue == false || d.Value == new DateTimeOffset(DateTime.Today)))
        .Select(kvp => kvp.Key);
```

I get:

```
1234 
2134 
2345
```